# How to reduce memory usage of program?

Tags: c#, memory

I am creating a (spatial database file)sdf file from the data fetched from Geodatabase file. I am not storing the data anywhere still memory and cpu usage of program is very high.I am using the file having huge database how can I increase performance? I have also tried to use finalize and dispose method.

```
static void GetFeatureData(Geodatabase geodatabase, string tablename, string sdffilepath)
{
    string query = "select * from " + tablename;
    int no = 1;

    foreach (Row row in geodatabase.ExecuteSQL(query))
    {
        IConnection con = OpenFDOSDFConnection(sdffilepath);
        IInsert insertCommand = (IInsert)con.CreateCommand(OSGeo.FDO.Commands.CommandType.CommandType_Insert);
        insertCommand.SetFeatureClassName(tablename);
        for (int nFieldNumber = 0; nFieldNumber < row.FieldInformation.Count; nFieldNumber++)
        {
            string fieldName = row.FieldInformation.GetFieldName(nFieldNumber);
            switch (row.FieldInformation.GetFieldType(nFieldNumber))
            {
                case FieldType.SmallInteger:
                    if (row.IsNull(fieldName))
                    {
                        insertCommand.PropertyValues.Add(new PropertyValue(fieldName, null));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        insertCommand.PropertyValues.Add(new PropertyValue(fieldName, new Int32Value(row.GetShort(fieldName))));
                    }
                    break;
                //All other datatypes

                case FieldType.Geometry:
                    if (!row.IsNull(fieldName))
                    {
                        switch (row.GetGeometry().geometryType.ToString())
                        {
                            case "Point": insertCommand.PropertyValues.Add(new PropertyValue("Geometry", geometryValue));
                                break;
                            //All other Geometry cases        
                        }
                    }

            }
            insertCommand.Execute();
            insertCommand.Dispose();
            con.Dispose();
            Console.WriteLine(no++);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a memory profiler. -OR- Poor man's method: Add some `Cosole.ReadLine()` and watch memory usage in TaskManager. This way you may find out when and where the memory gets used.

Comment: Also add some `GC.Collect()` to avoid fooling yourself.

Comment: Looks like you are loading the entire table into memory! Use paging...

Comment: Use [SqlBulkCopy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class. See also [Bulk Copy Operations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7ek5da1a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Could you maybe use just a single insertCommand (created outside of the loop) and just re-write the PropertyValues?